# Whether the system of matrix equations is always solvable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In recent days, I learned a linear algebra problem from one of my friends.
It can be stated as follows.

Given four matrices $A,B,C,D$, find three matrices $E,G,F$, not simultaneously zero, such that the following conditions (1), (2), (3) are satisfied:
$$
\begin{align*}
(1) &\quad  AE=EA, \cr
(2) &\quad BG=GB, \cr
(3) &\quad AF-FB=ED-CG.
\end{align*}
$$
The question is whether such $E,G,F$ always exist.

Also it is obvious that we can obtain $E,G$ by (1) and (2) easily. However the hard die 
is to satisfy condition (3). I just know when $A$ and $B$ have different spectra, we can obtain $F$ in a unique way.

Comment: A solution is E=G=F=0.

Comment: $E$ is usually the identity...

Comment: @Wadim: ...then why (1)? Anyway, my point was that the OP could wish to state the question more precisely. And a bit of context would not hurt either.

Comment: For 2x2 matrices, the solution set is equidimensional of codimension 8, according to Macaulay 2.

Comment: @Didier, the answer below suggests that $E$ can be taken as the identity matrix. So, my guess wasn't that bad! ;-)

Comment: @yaoxiao: it is considered impolite to edit your question in a way that makes existing answers unintelligible.  I have restored the question.

Comment: I have flagged for the moderators to lock the question. @yaoxiao: What you are doing now is spam.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $E=x I_n$, $G=y I_n$, then 1-2 are satisfied and the 3rd is a system of $n^2$ linear homogeneous equations with total number of variables equals to $n^2 + 2$, thus there are simultaneously non-zero solutions. of course, one can do better estimates on the dimension of the solution.